# Cannot build a unique index on a column with no duplicate values

Tags: firebird

First I ran

```
select beatid, count(*)
from beat
group by beatid
having count(*) > 1
```

And I got no rows as the result.

So then I ran

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX BEAT_IDX_UNQ ON BEAT (BEATID);
```

and got

> Invalid insert or update value(s): object columns are constrained - no
>   2 table rows can have duplicate column values. attempt to store
>   duplicate value (visible to active transactions) in unique index
>   "BEAT_IDX_UNQ".

What's up with that?

Comment: what database is this ?

Comment: Looks like corrupted index. Run validate database  `gfix -v -f` to check.

Comment: Backup and restore your database and try the query again. As Val Marinov says, this could indicate a corrupt index that 'hides' a row in queries that use that index; backup and restore will rebuild the index.

Comment: Because the database is perpetually in use, and I can't take it offline, I gbak'ed it and restored the backup to a new fdb. Of course, I was able to build the index on the BEAT table on the restored FDB. It's time to get onto IT to arrange for the active database to be gbak'd and restored. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: or I would try to prohibit using indices, if possible. `select beatid + 0, count(*) from beat group by 1 order by 2 descending` for integers, or ` '' || beatid` for VarChar.  Anyway, what are those columns? show us the schema of the table, its full declaration.

Comment: BEATID is an integer.

Comment: then "+ 0" would do. Just turning a column into an expression should in effect prohibit Firebird Core to using indexes and instead force it to sort the data anew and thus bypass index corruptions. Just for diagnostics purposes. Try both queries with and without "+0" and see how different would be their PLANs

Answer (score 3):

There can be more causes for situation like yours. First, you need to recheck if you have some pending transactions affecting "beat" relation, committing them or rolling back can resolve the problem. You can check system table `rdb$statements` for executing queries.

Also, it is question how NULLs are treated in the sense of unique values. You can consult the *[Firebird NULL Guide](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/nullguide.html)*, it can be find in the [Firebird documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/reference-manuals/). After all, if you still have the same problem backup/restore would solve.